# How to calm the IDE about not declared temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ide

When I design a temporary table as follows, the manager growls at the name *#Temp* and marks it with red highlight.

```
drop table #Temp
select * into #Temp
from Donkeys
```

When I hover over the highlight, the reason is - as expected - that the name isn't recognized.

> Cannot drop the table '#Temp', because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Now, I'm not a SQL developer - I come from C# and I'm spoiled by intellisense, Resharper and what not, so I dislike when something is highlighted (even although it works). I installed Management Studio 11.x just to get the intellisense working and I want to get my money worth, if possible.

The question is - can I do something about the highlight (purely visually, because the functionality is - as pointed out earlier - as it's supposed to)?

Please note that the question is **not** about why it happens or if it's a problem. I do understand perfectly well why and I'm declaring it to be a problem (yeah, I admit it's not the biggest issue but it's big enough for me to actually invest time asking). Also, I'm human (i.e. lazy-ish) so a simple solution will do.   :)

Comment: I think you need to check that the `#Temp` table is exists then `DROP` it ;).

Comment: @shA.t Nope. It does exists already as it's the second, third, fourth (etc.) run. As I mentioned - the query itself works as supposed to. It's just the visual effect that bugs me. (Of course, in production code, I'll certainly wouldn't drop stuff without checking. You're right about that!)

Comment: IMHO in SSMS many times you will see that red underlines also when you add a new entity and some other times, I usually ignore them ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

You are receiving this issue because #temp does not exist yet. You either need to check for it's existence like so:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null
begin
drop table #temp
end
select * into #Temp
from Donkeys
```

or you can just drop the table after you've used it:

```
select * into #Temp
from Donkeys
Drop table #Temp
```

Comment: Actually, the table **does** exist since the **previous** run. The first time I usually go without the dropping and **then** I add it. Every consecutive execution is then working well. I was hoping that the IDE somehow could detect that the temporary object actually does reside in the memory. But I guess, I'll need to live with the green underlining. Too much work to check for existence (while horsing around, that is - in production I'd always check, for sure).

Comment: Maybe try pressing Ctrl + Shift + R, this refreshes the intellisense which may rid you of your underlining if the table does exist.

Comment: **That** should be at the top of your reply. That's right-on-spot what I was looking for! I even update it for you. +1 for persistence!

Answer (score 2):

use like this way :-

```
If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#Temp') Is Not Null Drop Table #Temp;

select * into #Temp
from Donkeys
```

Comment: Good example. I wish that the IDE would realize that the object exists since the previous run but I guess this is the best I can get. +1 nice example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the table exists before trying to drop it of course.
Otherwise the IDE will keep on giving you red lines.

```
if exists(select 1 from tempdb.sys.tables where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#Temp'))
drop table #Temp

select * into #Temp
from Donkeys
```

It will also be better to rerun your script without having to select individual steps.